# How to write streaming dataset into Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Using Apache Spark 2.2: Structured Streaming, I am creating a program which reads data from Kafka and write it to Hive.
I am looking for writing bulk data incoming in Kafka topic @ 100 records/sec.

**Hive Table Created:**

```
CREATE TABLE demo_user( timeaa BIGINT, numberbb INT, decimalcc DOUBLE, stringdd STRING, booleanee BOOLEAN ) STORED AS ORC ;
```

**Insert via Manual Hive Query:**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE demo_user (1514133139123, 14, 26.4, 'pravin', true);
```

**Insert via spark structured streaming code:**

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName("testing");
conf.setMaster("local[2]");
conf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083");
SparkSession session = 
SparkSession.builder().config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

// workaround START: code to insert static data into hive
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE demo_user (1514133139123, 14, 26.4, 'pravin', true)";
session.sql(insertQuery);
// workaround END:

// Solution START
Dataset<Row> dataset = readFromKafka(sparkSession); // private method reading data from Kafka's 'xyz' topic

// **My question here:**
// some code which writes dataset into hive table demo_user
// Solution END
```

Answer (score -1):

you do not need to create the hive table when using the following,this gets created automatically

dataset.write.jdbc(String url, String table, java.util.Properties connectionProperties)

or use

dataset.write.saveAsTable(String tableName)

Comment: thanks for replying. but in structure streaming dataset doesn't work on write() function. It works on .writeStream() function.

Comment: @pravin .. have you found any solution for this ?